# exit(-1); error: boost::condition_variable::~condition_variable(): Assertion `!ret' failed

Tags: c++, boost

How to properly shutdown software?
With exit(-1); I get this error:

> /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable_fwd.hpp:85: boost::condition_variable::~condition_variable(): Assertion `!ret' failed.
> Aborted

Comment: At least on UNIX systems a negative error/return code is not valid. Use `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` for portable values. Also, prefer to `return` from `main` rather than call `exit` - `exit` will not cause all objects to be destroyed / call all destructors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: Ideally you'd signal all additional threads to end, join with them inside `main()`, cleanup any other resources, then return from `main()`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- and just for completeness, `exit(0)` is also portable and has the same effect as `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing works still get this error

Comment: Do you use globals? Are they in separate translation units? Can you move the lifetime of them info `main` and make sure they're deterministically destructed (RAII, e.g. using `unique_ptr`?)

Comment: Actually I have a code working which send SIGTERM and program is closed but not completely and need exit to terminal still

Comment: @PeteBecker Not quite: In OpenVMS, success is indicated by odd values and failure by even values and EXIT_SUCCESS is not 0.

Comment: @JesperJuhl — the C and C++ standards both require `exit(0)` (and `return 0;` from `main()`) to return an appropriate code to the OS to indicate success. If 0 isn’t an appropriate code the code that calls `main()` checks for 0 and returns an appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved my issue
I used

> kill(0,SIGINT);

Comment: Is that your resolution or the problem? Maybe you can explain how the problem was causing the message?

Comment: Problem was that after program shutdown (via c++ script) program was still kind of active so in other c++ script associated with the first one I added "exit(-1)" to shutdown completely and it helped but this error kept showing up every time. So i replaced "exit(-1)" for "kill(0,SIGINT)" and the error is gone.